# How to read folder name and its content from a zip folder in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react form in which I have a file input which selects zip folder. Inside the zip there is a folder and inside the folder there is a `__init__.py` file which has a dict e.g.

```py
info = {
    name = "Joe",
    age = "20"
}
```

I want to extract the `info` dict and convert it into js object so that I can use the `name` and `age` in other form input.

I tried to use `JSZip`

```py
const onChangeFile = (e) => {
    var new_zip = new JSZip();
    new_zip.loadAsync(e.target.files[0]).then(function (zip) {
      zip
        .folder("Test")
        .file("__init__.py")
        .async("string")
        .then(function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
    });
  };
```

I have to manually put the folder name which is not practical for other zip folders.

Comment: Your problem is with converting the string to object or with the folder name ?

Comment: Both, first I want to get the folder name, and then convert the string to object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps:

```js
const onChangeFile = (e) => {
    var new_zip = new JSZip();
    let folderName = "";
    new_zip.loadAsync(e.target.files[0]).then(function (zip) {
      zip?.forEach((entry) => {
        const entryParts = entry.split("/");
        if(entryParts[entryParts.length - 1] === "__init__.py") {
          folderName = entryParts.slice(0, entryParts.length - 1).join("/");
        }
      });
      zip?.folder(folderName)?.file("__init__.py")?.async("string").then(function (data) {
        let newData = `{${data}}`.replaceAll("=", ":");
        newData = newData.replace(/([{,])(\s*)([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+?)\s*:/g, '$1"$3":');
        const jsonData = JSON.parse(newData)
        console.log(jsonData);
      });
    });
  };
```